# How to create a tree diagram at the apex 5?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

What do I have to do to create a tree diagram in Oracle-Apex? I have tried everything and I can not generate the tree diagram.

I'm trying to generate the diagram with the siguienet query:

```
select case when connect_by_isleaf = 1 then 0 
when level = 1 then 1 else -1 end as status,
        level,
        ename as title,
        'icon-tree-folder' as icon,
        empno as value,
        ename as tooltip,
        null as link
   from emp
  start with mgr is null
connect by prior empno = mgr
  order siblings by ename
```

Answer (score 1):

What does it mean, you "can't create the tree diagram"? Why not?

The simplest way to do it is to:

- create page using the Wizard
- select **Tree** page type (otherwise, it either won't work or you'll make your life more complex than it should be)
- follow the Wizard's instructions
- select the table name (such as Scott's EMP table)

  - ID = EMPNO
  - Parent ID = MGR
  - Node text = ENAME
  - Start with = MGR
  - Start tree = Value is NULL
- accept the rest of suggested options
- run the page - the tree is here

Query looks like this:

```
select case when connect_by_isleaf = 1 then 0
            when level = 1             then 1
            else                           -1
       end as status, 
       level, 
       "ENAME" as title, 
       null as icon, 
       "EMPNO" as value, 
       null as tooltip, 
       null as link 
from "#OWNER#"."EMP"
start with "MGR" is null
connect by prior "EMPNO" = "MGR"
order siblings by "ENAME"
```

Basically, the same as yours (I just didn't make any changes, therefore column names are enclosed into double quotes, `FROM` clause contains the `#OWNER#`).

If data stored in the table makes the hierarchy, it'll *work*; there's no reason why it shouldn't.